# SyntaxError on Parse Cloud Code with `class ... extends` Parse.Object subclass declaration

Tags: parse-platform

The [Parse.com JS docs](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#objects-parse-object) say that I should be able to use the following syntax for declaring `Parse.Object` subclasses:

```
class ClassName extends Parse.Object {
  constructor() {
    // Setup code
  }
  // Other class code
}
Parse.Object.registerSubclass('ClassName', ClassName);
```

However, when I try to deploy cloud code like this, I get the following error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word in main.js:5`

Where the code `class ClassName extends...` is on line 5. Looks to me that the reserved keyword that is causing the issue is `class`. What's the issue here? Are Parse's docs wrong, or am I forgetting something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The javascript documentation you are referring to is for developing a javascript based application. As far as I know in cloud code you are restricted to functions only. Refer specifically to cloud code in the above documentation.

Comment: I wasn't quite sure about that from the documentation. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it on [Back4App](https://www.back4app.com) platform when using Clode Code.

First I defined the class in separate file named `Monster.js`. Example of the class was taken from [Parse Docs](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#parseobject)

```js
class Monster extends Parse.Object {
    constructor() {
    // Pass the ClassName to the Parse.Object constructor
    super('Monster');
    // All other initialization
    this.sound = 'Rawr';
  }

  hasSuperHumanStrength() {
    return this.get('strength') > 18;
  }

  static spawn(strength) {
    const monster = new Monster();
    monster.set('strength', strength);
    return monster;
  }
  // 1
  static registerClass() {
    Parse.Object.registerSubclass('Monster', Monster);
  }
}

// 2
module.exports = Monster
```

I refactored the class by adding static method `registerClass` on it which can be seen under **step 1**.

Then, under **step 2**, I exported this class as we would normally do it in NodeJS project.

After class is declared we can import it into `main.js` file.

```js
// 3
const Monster = require('./Monster')

Parse.Cloud.define('createMonster', req => {
    const strength = req.params.strength
    // 4
    Monster.registerClass()
    // Create Monster object
    const monster = Monster.spawn(strength)
    // Save Monster object
    monster.save(null, { useMasterKey: true })
})
```

**Step 3** shows that importing of a `Monster` class is done with `require` function.

Now whenever using this class in any of the Cloud Code functions you must register it before as this is performed in **step 4**.